The Quranic muqatta'at as Syriac numbering system
I am asking this question in linguistics se because it requires the knowledge of both arabic and Syriac to make a claim.
As we know the quran employs a few letters in the beginning of some surahs, nobody has been able to find their meanings. A Christian has proposed this as a theory

There is other syriac traces in the quran. Apparently 20% of the vocabulary contains syriac. The most obvious trace is them mysterious 3 letters that appear in 29 chapters at the beginning. They are actually a syriac numbering system, probably inadveringly copied from translated syriac christian documents that were used to write those chapters.

Here my question would be wether early Syriac churches actually did use these letters as their numbering system for scripture and does this interpretation make any sense considering most of the words in Syriac and Arabic have very similar roots but can have different meanings.
Thank you

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about linguistics, even though it may require knowledge of languages to answer. See the [help/on-topic] for details.

“A Christian has proposed” is quite an odd phrasing. Why does the religious affiliation of the originator of the theory matter?

@JanusBahsJacquet the theory may not have any credibility and might be put forward with a bias against islam

That should be decided based on the theory; its proposer’s religion, gender, age, skin colour or shoe size is irrelevant. There are lots of serious, reputable scholars of Islam who themselves happen to be Christian, Jewish, Hindu or atheists, and there are lots of bunkum theories about Islam forwarded by Muslims (and the same is true on both sides for Christianity, Judaism or Hinduism). Your phrasing is basically trying to discredit the theory as you mention it.

The Syriac alphabet does have a system of letter-based numerals. This system is essentially identical to that of Hebrew and (the first 22 numerals of) the Arabic Abjadi numerals.
There are also several features of the muqaṭṭaʿāt that seem to make an assumption that they neatly reflect such a system directly difficult, looking just at the sequence ʾAlif Lām Mīm الم, which occurs several times:

This would be 1+30+40 (or 71), but the use of lām and mīm together (i.e. with two numerals for the decads, rather than a single numeral: ʿayn for 70) would be unexpected.
The numerals are given in the wrong order. We would expect the higher value numerals to appear first.

There are numerological instances where words are read as numbers, where the rules are relaxed somewhat (e.g. you can have multiple letters for the decads, units, and hundreds, and the numerals can appear in any order), but this is typically done to link two words (or phrases) together, so this cannot be used as an explanation as to the odd form (if read as numbers).
There are also instances (at least in Hebrew) of certain sequences of numerals being respelt to avoid names of God or things that could be read as curses. Neither of these could apply here.
As such, it seems difficult at best to understand these as simply being numbers.
There have been attempts to read these numerologically along these lines, but they inevitably run deep into the weeds and end up having to invoke occult or mystical methods that fall outside the remit of scholarly philology and rendering their claims philologically implausible.

Was Syriac literature ever numbered this way?

what way? I've already established that these cannot be read simply as numbers. You could try to interpret them numerologically using the numeral system but all attempts to do so have had to resort to unscientific methods to produce any meaning

Oh ok so this wouldn't be a plausible explanation

correct, it's not plausible

I think a word is missing in "seem to make an assumption"?

@Draconis good spot
